# How to make custom array in python django

Tags: python, django

I have this list of dict

```
{"FieldFlags": "0", "FieldNameAlt": "Please forgive me", "FieldName": "field1", "FieldType": "Text", "FieldJustification": "Left", "FieldValue": "test"},
 {"FieldJustification": "Left", "FieldNameAlt": "Please forgive me", "FieldName": "min_speed", "FieldType": "Text", "FieldFlags": "0"},
 {"FieldJustification": "Left", "FieldNameAlt": "Please forgive me", "FieldName": "avg_speed", "FieldType": "Text", "FieldFlags": "0"}, 
 {"FieldJustification": "Left", "FieldNameAlt": "Please forgive me", "FieldName": "lowest_speed", "FieldType": "Text", "FieldFlags": "0"},
 {"FieldJustification": "Left", "FieldNameAlt": "Please forgive me", "FieldName": "air", "FieldType": "Text", "FieldFlags": "0"}, 
 {"FieldJustification": "Left", "FieldNameAlt": "Please forgive me", "FieldName": "slope", "FieldType": "Text", "FieldFlags": "0"}]
```

For my purpose i need to convert this array to something like

```
fields = [('field1','test'),('min_speed',''),('avg_speed','')..]
```

So basically i want the tuple of  `(FiedName,FieldValue)`

If fieldValue is not there , then it should be displayed as empty

How can i convert that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fields = [(d['FieldName'], d.get('FieldValue', '')) for d in your_list]
```

Comment: `d` is just a name for the values in `your_list` while iterating over them. It could have been anything, but I chose `d` as we're iterating over a list of **d** ictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map():

```
fields = map(lambda d: (d['FieldName'], d.get('FieldValue', '')), your_list)
```